# PyQGIS: draw layer/feature's bounding box

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, extents

I want to display a vector layer's bounding box in a print layout (or possibly a single feature's bounding box). Does QGIS have anything built-in to achieve this in the renderer/style? Or will I have to load a style/add a symbol layer with `bounds($geometry)`?

Answer (score 2):

`bounds($geometry)` in a Geometry Generator symbol layer will draw a box round every feature in a layer:

[image]

Best I can do for a whole layer with multiple features is a new virtual layer of the extent of the layer:

[image]

This should be a lot quicker than my first stab of the bounds of the union:

[image]

Comment: I'll accept this - thank you - if no-one comes up with any built-in QGIS "bounding box only" display option with a Python binding.